# Why random words from array doesn't show when I click the button?

Tags: java, android, arrays, random

I wanted to create a simple app that shows words/sentences randomly from a list that I've created every time the user click on the button.

Android Studio doesn't show any error but nothing happens when I click on the button.

Appreciate your help. Thank you

Here's my code.
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.arraytesting4;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> SList;
    TextView Sentence;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Sentence = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sentence);

    }


public void buttonClicked(View v){
    printJoke();
}

public void printJoke() {
    StringBuilder SentenceStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : SList) {
        SentenceStringBuilder.append(s + "\n");
    }
    Sentence.setText(SentenceStringBuilder.toString());
}
}
```

In SList.java

```
package com.example.arraytesting4;
import java.util.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SList extends MainActivity {
    public void Sentence(){

        ArrayList<String> SList = new ArrayList<String>();

        SList.add("Apple");
        SList.add("Banana");
        SList.add("Ciku");
        SList.add("Danny ate the others.");


    }
}
```

Comment: SList is a LOCAL variable in your method Sentence. It's different from the MEMBER variable SList declared in MainActivity.

Comment: Try using different name for the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to write following code in your onCreate after importing button,

```
clickMe.onClickListener((View v) -> {
    Sentence.setText(getRandomFromList(getSampleList())); 
});
```

Now add below two methods to create List & get a random from List,

```
private ArrayList<String> getSampleList(){
     ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
     list.add("Apple");
     list.add("Banana");
     list.add("Water Melon");
     list.add("Fruit X");
     list.add("Fruit Y");
     return list;
 }
 
 private String getRandomFromList(ArrayList<String> list){
     Random rand = new Random();
     return list.get(rand.nextInt(list.size()));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your hierarchy here doesn't have any sense. I don't know what you tried or thought but this is incorrect.

If you extends your `MainActivity` then your `Slist` is also an `Activity`, is your project even running?

There are different problems here :

1. You don't use `Sentence()` method anywhere
2. You are extending `MainActivity` to create a method of an `ArrayList`

An easy way should be create a method to initialise that `ArrayList` inside your `MainActivity` and then it should work.

Create a method to initialise the List and call this method inside `onCreate()`

```
private void initialiseArray(){
        SList = new ArrayList<>();
        SList.add("Apple");
        SList.add("Banana");
        SList.add("Ciku");
        SList.add("Danny ate the others.");
    }
```

Also remember to remove the `Slist` class.

**Note: I don't know if you just want to show one sentence on the `TextView` or all the items in the `ArrayList`, in this case how you did it would show all the items.**

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declare your button yet.

do something like this

```
Button *your button* = (Button) findViewById(R.id.*your button id*);
```

then, instead of creating buttonClicked function,
create button on click listener in your onCreate function.
something like this

```
*your button*.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 printJoke()
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add listener to your button.
So your buttons can know what they will do when someone click on them.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Sentence = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sentence);
    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(r.id.myButtonId);

    myButton.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
       buttonClicked(); //or you can delete buttonClicked Method and call printJoke Method here
    });

}
```